# How can I check to see what a user input in a different function?

Tags: python, function, variables, input

This is my first post on stackoverflow and I'm only asking because I truly am stuck. A good friend and I are trying to make a simple text based game(let's hear it for the 80's). It's my first day essentially with python and I've run into a problem. The player has a choice to pick up a dagger or to not. Later on I want this decision to come into play. Except I've no idea how to check and see what said player entered!
Here's my code
     Note:It crashes in the state it's in right now mainly because of me stumbling around trying to get this problem fixed.

```
def start():
        print("You wake up in a dank tunnel reeking of death and decomposition,")
        print("you have no weapons to defend yourself with.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n")
        print("You head north and find yourself at a four way tunnel.")
        print("\n")
        print("Down the west tunnel, you hear sounds which could have only come")
        print("from hell itself. With every sound uttered, your fear grows.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n")
        print("Down the north tunnel,  there is a room with a glimmering object")
        print("lying on the ground.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n")
        print("Down the East tunnel, there appears to have been a cave in.")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n")
        print("The South tunnel is the way you just came. \n")
        time.sleep(1)
        while True:
            r3 = input("Which way would you like to go?\n")
            if r3 == "west" or r3 == "West":
                print("The sounds are becoming Louder, do you continue or head back?")
                while True:
                    w1 = input("")
                    if w1 == "continue" or w1 == "Continue" or w1 == "west":
                            print("You continue further on...")
                            time.sleep(2.5)
                            westtunnel()
                    elif w1 == "head back" or w1 == "Head Back" or w1 == "back" or w1 == "Back":
                        print("\n")
                        print("The voices congregate behind you. No way your going back that way!\n")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        westtunnel()
                    else:
                        print("\n")
                        print("You couldn't possibly do anything else.\n")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        print("Greater minds prevail and you continue westward...\n")
                        time.sleep(2)
                        westtunnel()
            elif r3 == "north" or r3 == "North":
                print("You find a rusty dagger on the floor, stained with blood.")
                print("Do you want to pick up the dagger?")
                print("1: Yes, that seems useful!")
                print("2: No, I'm a bit of a pacifist you see.")
                while True:
                    pd = input("")
                    if pd == "1":
                        print("You slowly picked up the dagger.")
                        number = int(pd)
                        break
                    else:
                        print("You left the dagger. All alone.")
                        number = int(pd)
                        break
                print("You can go only go back the way you came.\n")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("You head back to the four way tunnel.")
            elif r3 == "east" or r3 == "East":
                print("\n")
                print("You can not go that way, there are rocks there. We told you this.\n")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("You go back to the four way tunnel")
            elif r3 == "south" or r3 == "South":
                print("\n")
                print("This is the room you awoke in, there is nothing of interest.\n")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("You head back to the four way tunnel")
            else:
                print("\n")
                print("You run into a corner, you hurt yourself in confusion. \n")
                time.sleep(1)
                print("You stumble back to the four way.")

def ladder():
    print("Do you have a dagger?!")
    number = pd
    if number == "1":
        print("Good you have it!")
        start()
        input("")
    else:
        print("awh...no dagger for you...")
        start()
        input("")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    menu()
```

Comment: Can you cut this code down to keep only what's relevant?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you don't use a lot of break statements in your code. So any scenario that was played would continue to play unless it calls another scenario. This is actually like recursive code and depending on how long the user plays your game, this might cause `stack overflow` (pun intended).

Answer (score 3):

Look into Python classes.

You probably want to create a Game State object that holds the results of decisions made in the course of the game. Then, later, when the results of those decisions matter, you check the state.

You will need to keep a reference to that game state object during your main game loop. However, keeping it in one object keeps all the state information organized, instead of keeping references to several disparate variables.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how I could create a Game state object. I tried searching for that on the web and found some vague articles at best. I do appreciate your help, though!